# Customizing Android ROM app data before flashing

Tags: android, apk, android-rom

I'm working at the IT-department of a rather large company, and we got Android phones for all of our employees. Every time someone quits or turn in their phone for any reason, we have to factory reset and then install all the required apps for our company, and this takes time.

I recently discovered that if you flash a custom rom, you can pick and choose what apps you want pre-installed in the ROM. This is good news for us and it got me thinking further.

So my question is, is there any way to customize the app data before flashing the ROM?

For example, we want our company's email app pre-installed with the correct user data already set up.

Comment: I'm somewhat late to the game but given your specific (business) use case I would highly advise against using a custom ROM unless you're able to install your own keys for Verified Boot, so that – after signing your custom ROM with these keys and installing it – you can re-lock the bootloader. Otherwise you open up a major security hole.

Comment: (continued) I think in general it would be a much better idea to use `adb` and USB debugging to sideload your apps than to install a custom ROM. Especially since keeping your ROM up-to-date and in sync with OTA updates (and security fixes!) by the manufacturer will be cumbersome to the point where you probably won't do it. (You would have to collect everyone's phone again, unlock the bootloader once again, flash the updated ROM, re-lock the bootloader and hand back the phone.)

Answer (score 2):

Look here http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=613, theres some socalled 'rom kitchens' that let you remove or add apps from/ to roms and make some customizations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about having the users data already in the email application, but you need to decompile the ROM, place your company's applications in the /system/app/ folder and then recompile the ROM. This will keep you from having to install the applications manually.